# Anchor tag not scrolling in EXM Generated in Outlook and GMail

Tags: exm, sitecore-query

I am sending email from Sitecore EXM 3.3. The email has a list of the Article as links on top and detailed articles list are at the bottom of the email. When user will click on an article link, the page should scroll to specific article item.

Article Anchor List code is being rendered by EXM as (HREF is being auto-generated)

```
<a style="color: #666666; display: block; text-decoration: none;" href="#Article_01">Article 01</a>

<a style="color: #666666; display: block; text-decoration: none;" href="#Article_02">Article 02</a>
```

And the bottom Article list is being rendered by EXM as

```
<a name="Article_01" href=""></a>

<a name="Article_02" href=""></a>
```

I have changed href="" to href="#" and removed href also. But it's not working.
Every article has Image and text also.

The HTML code is working fine in all Browsers but not working in Outlook and Gmail Client.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: looks like this is not a EXM problem, is a gmail issue . https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2010/11/the-trouble-with-anchor-links-in-email-newsletters/

Comment: you can try to add : <a name="Article_02" href="#Article_01"><span>Article</span></a>

Comment: When I paste the static HTML in rendering component and send through the EXM. It's working in OUTLOOK and GMAIL. It means that it's not OUTLOOK or GMAIL issue.

Comment: I will turn this into an answer, but EXM tries to rewrite all anchor tags when sending emails.  This occurs in the `<modifyHyperlink>` pipeline. My suspicion is that this pipeline is not expecting **#** an anchor link, and therefore rewrites it as an empty href.  I think you can add a processor to that pipeline to check for that type of link, and if found, just ignore the link rewrite.  This is just a guess at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anchor target was not working with `name` property in Outlook. But it is working when I add `id` and `name` property together in acnhor.

Working Anchor link 
`<a id="Article_01" name="Article_01" />`

Thanks to all for all answers.